# what header file is read_keycert function defined in

Tags: c++, ssl, grpc

i am trying the solution in

[Use SSL in gRPC client server communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623793/use-ssl-in-grpc-client-server-communication)

to add SSL to the gRPC Helloworld example, but it doesn't compile because it can't find read_keycert function ('read_keycert' was not declared in this scope).

what header file do i need to include?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Documentattion from this site, https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/structgrpc_1_1_ssl_server_credentials_options_1_1_pem_key_cert_pair.html. I suppose `read_keycert` is just a custom function to read the contents of your .key file and store it in a string

```
std::string read_keycert(const char* filename)
{
     std::ifstream file(filename);
     std::string temp;
     std::getline(file, temp);
     file.close();
     return temp;
}
```

Note : This function reads only one or single line from your .key or .cert file.

Add this to your program and the program should compile fine